# Dynamic import not working with turborepo internal package

Tags: typescript, next.js, turborepo

I am having some issues with a project i am developing. I am using turborepo and Nextjs. In the monorepo i have an app for the Nextjs app and a package where the ui components (lorry-ui) are implemented.

[image: Project structure]

The thing is that when i try to use `dynamic` NextJS function with my internal package nothing happens, but if i create a component in the app project and use dynamic the new chunk is created.

[image: Comparison of network details with two types of import]

Third request from top to bottom shows the new chunk for Field (local component) but there is no new chunk for OrangeCtaButton (package component)

I don't know what I could be doing wrong. Any idea what could be happening?

I have tested as I said before using components locally and from package to see if there was a difference. I have searched on internet If I am using the function wrong but I think that's how I should use it.